# Display diffrent image depending on timer

Tags: javascript, image, timer

I'm trying to display a different image depending on the timer's result and can't find a way through.  So far I have a start and stop button, but when I click stop, I want to use the value the timer is on and display an image(on alertbox or the webpage itself) depending on that value.

```
if( timer =>60){
     img.src("pizzaburnt.jpg");
}elseif (timer <=30){
   img.src("pizzaraw.jpg");
}
else{
img.src("pizzaperfect.jpg
}





///Time
        var check = null;

        function printDuration() {
            if (check == null) {
                var cnt = 0;

                check = setInterval(function () {
                    cnt += 1;
                    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = cnt;
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

    //Time stop
        function stop() {
                        clearInterval(check);
                        check = null;
                        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = '0';

                }

**HTML**
 <td>
  Timer :<p id="para">0</p>
 </td>
```

Any advice or dicussion would be great, thanks.

Comment: it is supported but you need the space use: `else if`

Comment: Are u trying to change image on time basis ? U r complicating things !

Comment: and the other guys comment was deleted, said: elseif is not supported

Comment: Yes, the comment was mine. Sorry about that. 

The question is not so clear to me. What have you tried?

Comment: @MikeBurnwood see my solution below, get rid of timer counting... it's redundant for this question imho

Comment: I just put that elseif part last min too show an idea of what i intended to do,I got it anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work better and it's more compact:

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var imageSrcs = ['pizzaRaw.jpg', 'pizzaPerfect.jpg', 'pizzaBurnt.jpg'];
var imageIndex = 0;
var interval = setInterval(animate, 30000); //change image every 30s
var animate = function() {
    //change image here
    //using jQuery:
    img.src(imageSrcs[imageIndex]);

    imageIndex++; //move index for next image

    if (imageIndex == imageSrcs.length) {
        clearInterval(interval); //stop the animation, the pizza is burnt
    }
}
animate();
```

Reason you wouldn't want to use an increment variable and a 1 second timer is because your just conflating your logic, spinning a timer, and making a bit of a mess when all you really want is the image to change every 30 seconds or whenever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you want more stages in your animation simply add more images to the imageSrcs array and then decrease the time in the setInterval method call so that it reflects proper pizza cooking time :D

Answer (score 0):

You need an `<img>` tag in your HTML like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Timer: <p id="para">0</p>
Image: <img id="image" />
</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript code will be like:

```
var handle;
var timerValue = 0;
var img = document.getElementById( "image" );
var para = document.getElementById("para");

function onTimer() {
  timerValue++;
  para.innerHTML = timerValue;
  if ( timerValue >= 60 ) {
    img.src( "pizzaburnt.jpg" );
  }else if ( timer <= 30 ) {
    img.src( "pizzaraw.jpg" );
  } else {
    img.src("pizzaperfect.jpg" );
  }
}

function start () {
  if ( handle ) {
    stop();
  }
  timerValue = 0;
  setInterval( onTimer, 1000 );
}

function stop () {
  if ( handle ) {
    clearInterval ( handle );
  }
}
```

Please make sure that these 3 files are in the same directory as your HTML file:

- pizzaburnt.jpg
- pizzaraw.jpg
- pizzaperfect.jpg